# $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime then there exists an integer $k$ such that $ak \equiv 1(\mod n) $.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

Let $n \in Z$, $n > 1$ and let $a \in Z$ with $1 \leq a \leq n$. Prove that if $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime then there exists an integer $k$ such that $ak \equiv 1(\mod n) $.

Proof: Suppose $(a,n) = 1$. Then $ax + ny = 1$ for some integers $x,y$.  Then $ny = 1 - ax$.
 So $n$ divides $1 - ax$ So $ax \equiv 1 (mod n)$.
Let  $x = k$.
Is this a correct approach?
Any help would be appreciated . Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think there's no problem with that.

Comment: Notice you do not need the restrictions on $n$ or $a$ either. You only need the stipulation $n \neq 0$.

Comment: A side remark: saying "$k := x$" in the end is more "logical"...